# Offset background image from center?

Tags: html, css

If I were talking about offsetting the background from the top I could just do this:

```
background-position: top 10px center;
```

I have just tried applying the same logic to a vertically central offset:

```
background-position: center 10px center;
```

Why does this not work? Is there a solution to do this purely using CSS or do I need to wrap the background in its own div (not my preference).

The HTML for the div:

```
<table id="tabs">
    <tr>
        <td id="tab-map">Map</td>
        <td id="tab-news">News</td>
        <td id="tab-timetables">Timetables</td>
        <td id="tab-favourites">Favourites</td>
        <td id="tab-more">More</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It is the `<td>` elements that have the background image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's unfortunately not how [background-center values](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/background-position#Values) work.  `center` is just shorthand for `50%`.  Thus what you attempted to do is `background-position: 50% 10px 50%;`, which as you noticed, doesn't work.  Unless you can represent that offset with a percentage value (e.g. `51%` or `49.5%`), `background-position` isn't going to be able to do what you need it to.  If it has to be a pixel based offset, I suggest just what you had considered: a wrapping container.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! I shall attempt to use a percentage value.